# Analyticity of Products

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Assume we have two functions $f,g:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ that are analytic and a third function $h:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $f=g\cdot h$. Can one now show that $h$ is analytic as well?

Of course $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ is open.

Comment: Should $\:g\cdot h\:$ be replaced with $\:g\circ h\:\:$? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: No it is a product of two functions.

Comment: Why does your title use the word "compositions"? $\;$

Comment: Oh your are right, is it possible to change the title?

Comment: Yes, there should be an edit button. $\;$

Comment: Found it and corrected title.

Comment: One can't show that $h$ is analytic, since $g$ could be identically zero. $\;$

Comment: Ok and what is if we assume that $f$ is non zero?

Comment: You probably also forgot the continuity assumption for $h$ and connectivity for $\Omega$ (in addition to $g$ not identically zero). With all these assumptions, claim follows from Riemann's removable singularity theorem.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't: try $f(z) = z$, $g(z) = z^2$, $h(z) = 1/z$ for $z \ne 0$ with $h(0)$ arbitrary.